# Dynamic template slot name is implicitly any

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I am trying to render dynamic slots and the following works in respect to rendering but typescripts throws error on `#[slotName]` stating `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type 'Readonly....`. I even tried suppressing the error but somehow the error isnt being suppressed as well.

How can this error be dealt with?

```
<template>
  <v-text-field v-model="value" :error-messages="errorMessage" hide-details="auto">
    <template v-for="(_, slotName) in $slots" #[slotName]="slotData">
      <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="slotData" />
    </template>
  </v-text-field>
</template>  

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useField } from 'vee-validate'

const { value, errorMessage } = useField(() => props.name)
const props = defineProps({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  }
})

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: #[slotName.toString()]

Comment: Nope, doesnt work using toString()

Comment: Hi can you provide, the script part entirely and your vue, vue-tsc and typescript version maybe please ? Thanks

Comment: @Samuel its vue 3.3.4, Nuxt 3.6.0, typescript 5.0.4. I don't have vue-tsc. I have added in the script section in the question.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Am using `<!-- @vue-skip -->` just before the line containing `#[slotName]`. Not a good solution though.

Comment: I pasted your code in my component and it doesn't show any errors, try to upgrade the volar extension

Comment: I am running volar 1.8.8. What is your version?